# Error while trying to use references in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to do a replace both in the middle of a row with sed, and add a new line after said line, with some content from the matching line. But the way i'm doing it does not work.

```
sed '/The \(matching\) line/{s/line/lines/;s/$/\nThe new \1 line/}'
```

This returns "invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS". How do I get the reference from the matched row to be available for the substitution match?

Edit: What I want the result to be is this:

Input:

```
The matching line
```

Output:

```
The matching lines
The new matching line
```

Comment: You should use & but not \1

Comment: Well, that helped removing the error message. But, it did not print the matched text.

Comment: OK, Sorry, I just misunderstood what you want.  Do you mean there is a $ in the (matching)?

Comment: I first match a row, then in that row I substitute something, and then substitute the end of the line with a line break and more text, and in that text, I'm trying to add a matched reference from the first line.

Comment: Updated question with example of how I want it to work.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will meet your question: `sed 's/The \(.*\) line/The \1 lines\nThe new \1 line/'`

Comment: Seems like that did the trick, thanks.

Comment: Maybe others will have better solution, it is really not so good.

Comment: @Nancy: you should make it an answer anyway, as by default your comment is hidden (and I posted exactly the same answer, before reading your comment. I deleted my post after that.)

Comment: @Qeole Yes, sorry for that. And posted my answer. I just think maybe others will have better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post my answer below while it's hidden in the comment.

```
sed 's/The \(.*\) line/The \1 lines\nThe new \1 line/'
```

Comment: +1 for a portable `sed` solution, though to really make it truly portably, you can't rely on `\n` in the replacement string and must instead splice in an `\ `-escaped ANSI C-quoted newline literal (`$'\n'`): `sed 's/The \(.*\) line/The \1 lines\'$'\n''The new \1 line/'` - alternatively, insert a literal newline after the `\ ` (effectively spreading the command across 2 lines).

Comment: @mklement0 Sorry, but it just can't work. I'm not sure what is C-quoted newline used for.

Comment: Some `sed` variants - e.g., FreeBSD/OSX `sed` - do not support control-character escapes such as `\n` in the replacement string. Therefore, you must insert an actual newline char. into the `sed` script (which then requires a preceding `\ ` to mark it as a newline that is part of the replacement string). `$'\n'` expands to a newline using a `bash` feature called [ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) - note the carefully placed single quotes. What platform do you see my solution fail on?

Comment: @mklement0 My platform is Redhat. Let me deeply check the ANSI C quoting

Comment: I don't have Red Hat, but I can confirm that my command works on the similar Fedora 20.

Comment: @mklement0 Ridiculously, you command works for me now. And it's OK for bash but not tcsh. Also I think just \n will always work fine. Still your comments are very useful.

Comment: ANSI C quoting works in `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh` (others?), but is not part of POSIX (`[t]csh` is an entirely different beast). If ANSI C quoting is not available, insert a literal newline (spread across two lines) or use command substitution `$(printf '\n')`. `I think just \n will always work fine` - trust me, it will not - try any FreeBSD or OSX machine.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for your advice, I just haven't worked with FreeBSD or OSX. I'll remember it and try it once I meet them.

Comment: I don't think I will use it on FreeBSD/OSX, but I will try to remember in case I experience the same problem on one of those machines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you system supports extended regex:

```
echo 'The matching lines' | sed -re 's/The\s+(.*)\s+line/The \1 lines\nThe new \1 line/'
The matching lines
The new matching lines
```